# Radius convergence of $f(z) = \frac{1}{1+\sin^2(z)}$

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion

Determine the radius convergence of Taylor's series for the following function: $$f(z) = \frac{1}{1+\sin^2(z)}$$ around  $z_0 = 0$.
Now here is what I have tried to do:
$\sin^2(z) = 1 - \cos^2(z)$ , $\cos^2(z) = \frac{1}{2}(\cos(2z) + 1)$

so the last form would be $\frac{2}{1-\cos(2z)}$
, we know that $$\cos(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{z^{2n}}{(2n)!}$$

then
$\cos(2z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{(2z)^{2n}}{(2n)!}$ ,
So the last form would be $\frac{2}{1-\ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{(2z)^{2n}}{(2n)!})}$

which is $\frac{2}{-\ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{(2z)^{2n}}{(2n)!}}$
And I am stuck here , I have no idea what to do next

**If for f(z) a finite number of singular points in the complex plane, then the radius of convergence R is
The distance from z0 to the nearest singular point.**

Comment: The radius of convergence corresponds to the length between the point of expansion (here $z_0=0$) and the nearest undefined/singular point. In your case, $f(z)$ diverges when $1+\sin^2(z)=0$, hence $\sin(z)=\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}=\pm i$, which is equivalent to $e^{2iz}\pm2e^{iz}-1=0$. I let you go on from there.

Comment: Well yes we have thought about that , but that works when there is finite points , not infinite singular points

Comment: What do you mean by "there is finite points" and by "infinite singular points"? And why do you think the previous hint "does not work"?

Comment: Check my edit in the post

Comment: What do you mean by "singular point that is not discontinuous", and why do you believe that the finiteness of the set of singular point is necessary in the theorem mentionned of the 1st comment?

Comment: I have made a mistake when I wrote  discontinuous , but that is a rule the professor gave us , this is not something I made up , and me and others did like the first comment , but the professor said it was wrong for that reason

Comment: A continuous spectrum of singularities would be problematic, but a *countably* infnite number of singularities doesn't change anything to expansions and radii of convergence.

Comment: No matter how is the set of singularities (continuous, countably infinite, finite...), the radius of convergence around $z_0$ is the distance from $z_0$ to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The radius of convergence is the distance from $0$ to the nearest non-removable singularity. And we have\begin{align}1+\sin^2(z)=0&\iff\sin(z)=\pm i\\&\iff\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}=\pm i\\&\iff e^{iz}-e^{-iz}=\mp2\\&\iff\left(e^{iz}\right)^2\pm2e^{iz}-1=0\\&\iff e^{iz}=1+\sqrt2\vee e^{iz}=1-\sqrt2\vee e^{iz}=-1+\sqrt2\vee e^{iz}=-1-\sqrt2\\&\iff iz\in\log\left(1+\sqrt2\right)+2\pi i\Bbb Z\vee iz\in\log\left(\sqrt2-1\right)+\pi i+2\pi i\Bbb Z\vee{}\\&\qquad\vee iz\in\log\left(-1+\sqrt2\right)+2\pi i\Bbb Z\vee iz\in\log\left(1+\sqrt2\right)+\pi i+2\pi i\Bbb Z\\&\iff z\in i\log\left(1+\sqrt2\right)+2\pi\Bbb Z\vee z\in\pi+i\log\left(\sqrt2-1\right)+2\pi\Bbb Z\vee{}\\&\qquad\vee z\in i\log\left(-1+\sqrt2\right)+2\pi\Bbb Z\vee z\in\pi+i\log\left(1+\sqrt2\right)+2\pi\Bbb Z.\end{align}Of all these numbers, the ones which are closer to $0$ are $i\log\left(\pm1+\sqrt2\right)$. Therefore, the radius of convergence is $\bigl|\log\left(\pm1+\sqrt2\right)\bigr|\approx0.88$.

Comment: If f(z) has infinite singular points, it is not possible to find a single radius of convergence for the function's power series expansion. radius of convergence for a power series expansion is determined by the behavior of the coefficients of the series, and if a function has infinite singular points, the behavior of the coefficients will vary depending on the location of the expansion point. In such cases, one could say that the radius of convergence is valid only in certain regions of the complex plane and it is not possible to give a global statement about the radius of convergence.

Comment: Says who?${}{}$

Comment: @MayyasHaj The radius of convergence is the ***smallest*** distance between the expansion center and a singularity; so yes, expansion are valid *locally* around the point of expansion; that's all the point of expansion and radius of convergence.

Comment: Maybe I understood all the idea wrong, thousand apologies if I made a mistake , but this is word for word from Tel Aviv university professor,
let $f(z)$ be analytic in complex except to finite points that $\lim_{z \to z_0} f(z)$ does not exist , then radius of $f(z)$ to the power series is the smaller distance between $a$ and the point $z_0$ can you explain this to me please?

Comment: What you wrote is just fine, but there is no need to deal only with the case in which there are only finitely many points at which $f$ is undefined. Take $\frac1{\cos(z)}$, for instance. It is undefined at infinitely many points. And the radius of convergence of its Taylor series centered at $0$ is $\frac\pi2$, since $\pm\frac\pi2$ are the non-removable singularities of $\frac1{\cos(z)}$ closer to $0$.

Answer (score 2):

If a power series $P(z) = \sum a_nz^n$ converges on an open disc $\{z : |z| < r\}$ and this function $P(z)$ has an analytic continuation to all points on the circle $\{z : |z| = r\}$, then (by using compactness of $\{z : |z| = r\}$) the original power series $\sum a_nz^n$ converges on a bigger open disc $\{z : |z| < r+\varepsilon\}$, so the function $P(z)$ defined by that original power series has an analytic continuation to that bigger open disc.

Theorem. *If $f(z)$ is a meromorphic function on $\mathbf C$ that is analytic at $0$ $($so it has no poles on some open disc around $0$$)$, then the radius of convergence of the power series for $f(z)$ at $0$ is the distance from $0$ to the nearest pole for $f(z)$.*

*Proof*.  Let $R$ be the distance from $0$ to the nearest pole of $f(z)$, so $f$ is analytic on $\{z : |z| < R\}$.  Let the power series for $f(z)$ at $0$ have radius of convergence $r$.

We show $r \leq R$ by contradiction. If $r > R$ then that series would be analytic on $\{z : |z| < r\}$, so it must agree with $f$ on  $\{z : |z| < r\}$ (uniqueness of meromorphic continuation), but $f$ is not analytic on that disc because of its pole with absolute value $R$, which is less than $r$.

Suppose $r < R$. Since $f$ is analytic on $\{z : |z| < R\}$ while its power series at $0$ converges on the smaller disc $\{z : |z| < r\}$ and is analytic on all $z$ with $|z| = r$, that power series at $0$ converges on a bigger disc $\{z : |z| < r + \varepsilon\}$, so the radius of convergence of that series is bigger than $r$.

Thus $r = R$. $\Box$

Apply this to $1/(1 + \sin^2 z)$, which is meromorphic on $\mathbf C$ with poles precisely where $\sin^2 z = 1$, which is equivalence to
$\sin z = \pm i$, so you just need to solve $\sin z = i$ and $\sin z = -i$ and find the smallest solution. Since $\sin z = -i$ is equivalent to $\sin \overline{z} = i$ (because $\overline{\sin z} = \sin \overline{z}$), the solutions to $\sin z = i$ and $\sin z = -i$ come in conjugate pairs, so it suffices to look at solutions of $\sin z = i$:
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{e^{iz} - e^{-iz}}{2i} = i & \Longleftrightarrow & e^{iz} - e^{-iz} = -2 \\
&  \Longleftrightarrow & e^{iz}  + 2 - e^{-iz} = 0 \\
&  \Longleftrightarrow & e^{2iz} + 2e^{iz}  - 1 = 0.
\end{eqnarray*}
The roots of $w^2 + 2w - 1 = 0$ are $w = (-2 \pm \sqrt{8})/2 = -1 \pm \sqrt{2}$, so we need to solve
$$
e^{iz} = -1 + \sqrt{2} \ \ {\rm and } \ \ e^{iz} = -1-\sqrt{2}.
$$
and find the solution $z$ where $|z|$ is minimal.  The other answer discusses that.